# How to add a column with a default value to an existing sql table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. So, I have already filled sql table with user_id and user balance.
I want to add a new column with rating. The default rating must be filled with fives.

From such table state

| user_id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2000000001 | 50 |
| 187638781 | 110 |

I need to get this

| user_id | balance | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000001 | 50 | 5 |
| 187638781 | 110 | 5 |

What's the best way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the table (here, named test1) to add the column with the default:

```
alter table test1 add column rating int default 5;
```